# How to do pattern match on fields of 2 records?

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

```
type A =
  {
    ...
    id: int;
    ...
  }
```

I wish i could do this

```
let Add (x:A) (y:A) =
     match x,y with
      | {x.id=0,y.id=1} -> ...
```

And is there any trick to define the function if i don't care about the order of `x` and `y` (so that the function is symmetric) also i don't mind whether the parameter is a `tuple (x,y)` or a higher order function `x,y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let add (x: A) (y: A) =
     match x.id, y.id with
     | 0, 1 | 1, 0 -> (* do some thing *)
     | _ -> (* do some thing else *)
```

If you only care about a field, do pattern matching directly on it. And you can use [Or pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) to have a symmetric function.

Answer (score 12):

Another syntax for this is:

```
let add x y =
    match x, y with
    | {id = 0}, {id = 1} | {id = 1}, {id = 0} -> ..
    | _ -> ..
```

See Record Pattern section at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it's matching on the records and not on integers.

Comment: @gradbot: I'm hesistant to use this because according to OP's question, there are more fields for which we don't know.

Comment: @pad, quoting the manual: "The record pattern is used to decompose records to extract the values of fields. The pattern does not have to reference all fields of the record; any omitted fields just do not participate in matching and are not extracted."

Comment: @gradbot is there any difference whether i match on records or on integers? Why is this answer better than pad's ones?

Comment: @colinfang if you're matching on records then you are not tied to field order.  You also don't have to type out all the fields.  You could for example match against an existing record.  Also in toyvo comments he mentions that you don't have to match against all fields in a record while you will if you're matching against a tuple.

Comment: @colinfang there are pros and cons; the main advantage of record patterns is that they compose with other patterns, e.g. `match r with { list = x::xs }`.